# SQLite PHP Not Filling HTML Table

Tags: javascript, php, html, sqlite

I am making an inventory using HTML and SQLite, using PHP to connect to the server and extract data. After extracting data, I need to populate an HTML table however this is not working. When I try to do console.log in order to see what's working, it does not show up in Chrome console. :(

Please ask if the database file is needed as it is a local database file in the working folder.

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
table th {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
    animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

/* Go from zero to full opacity */
@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

/* Style buttons */
.btn {
  background-color: DodgerBlue; /* Blue background */
  border: none; /* Remove borders */
  color: white; /* White text */
  padding: 12px 16px; /* Some padding */
  font-size: 16px; /* Set a font size */
  cursor: pointer; /* Mouse pointer on hover */
}

/* Darker background on mouse-over */
.btn:hover {
  background-color: RoyalBlue;
}

.btnadd {
  background-color: DodgerBlue; /* Blue background */
  border: none; /* Remove borders */
  color: white; /* White text */
  padding: 12px 16px; /* Some padding */
  font-size: 16px; /* Set a font size */
  cursor: pointer; /* Mouse pointer on hover */
}

/* Darker background on mouse-over */
.btnadd:hover {
  background-color: RoyalBlue;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
<head>
    <title>Inventory Server</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" a href="InventoryServer.css"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<body>
    

<h2 style="text-align: center">Welcome to the inventory!</h2>
    
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <button class="btnadd" id="btnadd"><i class=material-icons>add_circle</i></button>

<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLocation(event, 'Kitchen')" id="defaultOpen">Kitchen</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLocation(event, 'Shed')">Shed</button>
</div>
    
<div id="Kitchen" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Kitchen</h3>
    <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Unit</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
        <?php

$db = "inventory.db";

$handle = sqlite_open($db) or die("Could not open database");

$query = "SELECT Name,Quantity,Unit,Description FROM kitchen ";

$result = sqlite_query($handle, $query) or die("Error in query: ".sqlite_error_string(sqlite_last_error($handle)));


while($row = sqlite_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Name']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Quantity']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Unit']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Description']?></td>
                </tr>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
<?php
sqlite_close($handle);
?>

        
</table>
</div>

<div id="Shed" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Shed</h3>
    <table style="width: 100%">
   <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Unit</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <?php
            $connect = mysql_connect("inventory.db","root", "", "inventory");
            if (!$connect) {
                die(mysql_error());
            }
            $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shed ");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['quantity']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['unit']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['description']?></td>
                </tr>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
        
            </tbody>
</table>
</div>


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="btnAddForm" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2 style="text-align: center">Add New Item To Inventory</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form action="#" method="post" role="form" data-toggle="validator" class="form-container">
  <div class="form-group margin-top-m">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Name Of Item: </label>
    <input type="text" id="nameOfItem" name="nameOfItem" class="form-control" data-error="Please enter the item name!" required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="quantity" class="control-label">Quantity of Item: </label>
    <input type="text" id="quantityOfItem" name="quantityOfItem" class="form-control required" data-error="Please enter the quantity of the item!" required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mid-col">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="unitOfItem" class="control-label">Item Unit: </label>
     <select name="unitOfItem" id="unitOfItem" class="form-control required" data-error="Please select a unit!" required>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="piece">piece(s)</option>
    <option value="grams">g</option>
    <option value="kg">kg</option>
    <option value="mL">mL</option>
    <option value="L">L</option>
    <option value="item">item(s)</option>
     </select>
     <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mid-col">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="place" class="control-label">Select a place: </label>
     <select name="place" id="place" class="form-control required" data-error="Please select the item location!" required>
                <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Kitchen">Kitchen</option>
    <option value="Shed">Shed</option>
     </select>
     <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
        <div class="form-group">
    <label for="descriptionOfItem" class="control-label">Item description: </label>
    <input type="text" id="descriptionOfItem" name="descriptionOfItem" class="form-control required" data-error="Please enter a valid item description!" required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="margin-0"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg orange w-100 margin-top-s">Submit</button></p>
 </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="require.js"></script>
    
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('btnAddForm');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("btnadd");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}



document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

function openLocation(evt, locationName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(locationName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```